# Cannot find declaration of element nifty JME

Tags: jmonkeyengine, nifty-gui

I'm new to nifty. I am trying to learn how to create nifty GUI in JMonkey Engine game. I'm going through tutorials and tried to run project. Project runs fine but I get following error when I tried to edit xml:

**Cannot find declaration of element nifty**

Below is my start.xml code:

```
<nifty xmlns="http://nifty-gui.sourceforge.net/nifty.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://nifty-gui.sourceforge.net/nifty.xsd http://nifty-gui.sourceforge.net/nifty.xsd">
<useStyles filename="nifty-default-styles.xml" />
<!-- Screen Codes here-->
</nifty>
```

I guess most possible reason is that above namespace might have been deprecated and already been replaced. Or there might be other steps that I have to perform in JME SDK to make it recognize nifty tag. Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, tested in JMonkey SDK 3.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nifty xmlns="http://nifty-gui.sourceforge.net/nifty-1.3.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://nifty-gui.sourceforge.net/nifty-1.3.xsd http://nifty-gui.sourceforge.net/nifty-1.3.xsd">
    <useStyles filename="nifty-default-styles.xml" />
</nifty>
```

Comment: Your namespace is working. All we needed was to include version for nifty. thanks